# Versatile DatePicker control which satisfies these requirements

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am looking for a ready made control, ASP.NET server control or jQuery, or close enough which satisfies these requirements for a ASP.NET app:

1- Supports a year view (can display 12 months).
2- Ability to select a date range using Click on start date - shift click on end date and it selects all the days in between.

3- A date range can span more than one month. Start date can be in one month and end date in another month and it selects all days in between.

4- Can deselect a day inside a selected range (using ctrl-click).
5- Can select multiple individual days using ctrl-click. (Can do this across 12 months).
6- Can select multiple date ranges. (none of the controls I know supports this. When I select another date, the days in the older range disappear)
7- Selected dates will be saved in a database and I need to support ability to display previously selected dates when page renders the datepicker.
8- Need source code to be able to customize

There probably doesn't exist a control which does all this. The closest ones I have found so far:

1- [JS Calendar](http://www.dynarch.com/static/JSCal2/index.html). Can't select more than one date range. Can't display more than one month?

2- [DatePicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#about). Can't select more than one date range. Can't multiselect.

3- Telerik RadCalendar. All I know I can multiselect. No date range.  Need to purchase whole ASP.NET suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one from [EssentialObjects.com](http://EssentialObjects.com) did it. The one from about.com was second. Telerik's datepicker does a postback every time I changed the month which I didn't like.